Two ways of meta-analysis: Which one is preferred?
Suppose that I have $k=1, 2, 3...K$ studies with the same set of a continuous independent variable $Y$ and dependent variables $X$. The effect between studies may be different, and I want to run a meta-analysis.
One way I know is to run a regression.  I can create a $(K-1)$ dimensional dummy variable of $Z$ and run a linear regression with random effects. If $j$ is the study indictor and $i$ is the sample indicator:
$$Y_{ij}=\beta X_{ij}+\gamma_j Z_{ij}+\epsilon$$
$$\gamma_j\sim N(0,\tau^2)$$
$$\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$$
Or if there aren't many studies, I can do a fixed effect model:
$$Y_{ij}=\beta X_{ij}+\beta_j Z_{ij}+\epsilon$$
$$\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$$
However, I also see the practice of doing the analysis individually for each study and calculating the weighted average of log p-values (possibly weighted by sample sizes or square roots of sample sizes), as the following thread shows:
When combining p-values, why not just averaging?
I am new to meta-analysis. Can anyone give me a brief introduction to which method is preferred? Thank you!

In descending order of preference:

Use all studies' individual data sets combined through a mixed model.
Combine effect sizes using a meta-analytic random effects model.
Combine effect sizes using a meta-analytic fixed effects model.
Combine $p$-values.

The first option is the most efficient and allows the greatest flexibility in modelling options. Unfortunately, it is almost never an actual option, because data for all individual studies is rarely available.
A fixed effects meta-analytic model assumes an observed effect size $\hat{\theta}_k$ is subject to sampling error $\epsilon_k$: $$\hat{\theta}_k=\theta + \epsilon_k$$
But studies vary not only due to sampling error. Small differences in study design mean that each individual study estimates its own effect size  $\theta_k$. This is the rationale for using a meta-analytic random effects model: $$\begin{aligned}\hat{\theta}_k &= \theta_k + \epsilon_k \\ \\ \theta_k &= \mu + \zeta_k \end{aligned}$$
Here, $\zeta_k$ is error due to study-heterogeneity and $\epsilon_k$ is error due to sampling.
Hence, the second option not only considers the outcome of a fixed experiment to vary, but also allows the experiment itself to vary. This is almost always a more realistic assumption, but as you noted, it cannot always be estimated for a small number of studies.
Lastly, combining $p$-values just provides an overall assessment of significance. Any of the options above can provide that as well, and can provide much more interesting information in addition.
Since you mentioned you just got into meta-analysis, I really recommend the book Doing Meta-Analysis in R. I used the same notation used in that book. A full citation is included below.

Harrer, M., Cuijpers, P., Furukawa, T.A., & Ebert, D.D. (2021). Doing Meta-Analysis with R: A Hands-On Guide. Boca Raton, FL and London: Chapman & Hall/CRC Press. ISBN 978-0-367-61007-4.

Thank you! So if I have the data matrix for every individual dataset, I can use option (1). If I only have the estimated effect size, I can use options (2) and (3). Is that right?

@processing_statistician Yes, that's right!

Got it. I will look up the book. Thanks again!
